# Eliminate null entry in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, null, default

Is there any property to remove the first (and empty) item in a combobox with style DropDownList ? In other words, I would like to choose the default selected item for a combobox.

I know i can validate the selected item with code, but i want to avoid showing message boxes to the user.

Comment: Try to set `SelectedIndex` property to 0.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set the `comboBox.SelectedIndex` property to 0 to set the selection to the first item in the combobox.

Comment: You have to remember to add `comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;` **AFTER** you've populated your combo box, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: if i do double click it get null value again

Answer (score 4):

You should set the `Text` or `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue` property. In this way the combobox updates the text that's is showing and removes the first empty item (that actually is not a real item).

Comment: That's correct, and worked pefectly.

The SelectedIndex property was what i wanted.

Thank you all.